# Where in the database is the password reset form's expiration date set?

Tags: 7, users

I'd like to be able to change the text in the temporary login page but I don't know where the expiration date for the form can be found. Getting the username is simple enough and I left the login button as is. The date is the only thing left.

Alternatively, can I do this in the drupal admin without having to code anything? Something similar to the email alerts, including options for multiple languages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text for the One time password form is located in [`user_pass_reset`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.pages.inc/function/user_pass_reset/7) form function in core.

While the user's password reset notification mail may be configured from the admin menu (**Administer >> Configuration >> People >> Account Settings**) there's no similar Admin UI based configuration of the reset form itself.

Though there doesn't seem to be a module to customize the form itself (based on my search), there do appear to be modules that offer alternative password reset methods that you could look at namely [Password Reset](https://drupal.org/project/password-reset) and [Simple Password Reset](https://drupal.org/project/simple_pass_reset).

If you could consider taking a coding way, this could be achieved by using a [`hook_form_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) or [`hook_form_FORM_ID_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7)

As for the expiration date drupal uses a default of 86400 seconds (24 hours). It would be stored in the `variable` table in the database with the name `user_password_reset_timeout` (note that when present the value 86400 would be serialized like all values in that table). If you wish to change this value consider doing it using [`variable_set`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/variable_set/7) through code. The equivalent [drush command](http://drush.ws/#variable-set) would appear an easier option though. Do make sure to update the email content on expiry time to avoid any confusion.